# BLE Connect fails with page timeout

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, pi-3b+, bluez

I've got a custom BLE 4.1 device and I'm trying to connect it to Raspberry PI 3 B+ using hcitool, gatttool, bluetoothctl, ..., without success.

The device is an NRF BLE chip with the Nordic UART Service.

So far what I got is:

1. The device shows up in a "hcitool lescan"
2. bluez does all the connection attempts, seems to connect but disconnects immediately afterwards
3. hci0 (raspberry pi) fails equally to two other dongles (hci1, hci2)
4. Pairing fails as well
5. Connecting from ESP32 - arduino works fine
6. bluetoothd is already started with --experimental -d
7. NRFConnect on an android phone works just fine

Output of hcitool:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo hcitool -i hci0 lescan
LE Scan ...
FD:B8:73:ED:6B:CD 
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo hcitool -i hci0 cc
FD:B8:73:ED:6B:CD Can't create connection: Input/output error
```

Output of btmon:

```
@ RAW Op

en: hcitool (privileged) version 2.22         {0x0006} [hci0] 35.351116
< HCI Command: Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) plen 13         [hci0] 35.351195
        Address: FD:B8:73:ED:6B:CD (OUI FD-B8-73)
        Packet type: 0xcc18
          DM1 may be used
          DH1 may be used
          DM3 may be used
          DH3 may be used
          DM5 may be used
          DH5 may be used
        Page scan repetition mode: R2 (0x02)
        Page scan mode: Mandatory (0x00)
        Clock offset: 0x0000
        Role switch: Allow slave (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                      [hci0] 35.351618
      Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Connect Complete (0x03) plen 11                   [hci0] 40.475007
        Status: Page Timeout (0x04)
        Handle: 11
        Address: FD:B8:73:ED:6B:CD (OUI FD-B8-73)
        Link type: ACL (0x01)
        Encryption: Disabled (0x00)
@ MGMT Event: Connect Failed (0x000d) plen 8          {0x0003} [hci0] 40.475087
        BR/EDR Address: FD:B8:73:ED:6B:CD (OUI FD-B8-73)
        Status: Connect Failed (0x04)
@ MGMT Event: Connect Failed (0x000d) plen 8          {0x0005} [hci0] 40.475087
        BR/EDR Address: FD:B8:73:ED:6B:CD (OUI FD-B8-73)
        Status: Connect Failed (0x04)
@ MGMT Event: Connect Failed (0x000d) plen 8          {0x0004} [hci0] 40.475087
        BR/EDR Address: FD:B8:73:ED:6B:CD (OUI FD-B8-73)
        Status: Connect Failed (0x04)
@ MGMT Event: Connect Failed (0x000d) plen 8          {0x0002} [hci0] 40.475087
        BR/EDR Address: FD:B8:73:ED:6B:CD (OUI FD-B8-73)
        Status: Connect Failed (0x04)
@ MGMT Event: Connect Failed (0x000d) plen 8          {0x0001} [hci0] 40.475087
        BR/EDR Address: FD:B8:73:ED:6B:CD (OUI FD-B8-73)
        Status: Connect Failed (0x04)
@ RAW Close: hcitool                                  {0x0006} [hci0] 40.476108
```

output of bluetoothd:

```
Mar 28 11:56:01 raspberrypi bluetoothd[3884]: src/adapter.c:connect_failed_callback() hci0 FD:B8:73:ED:6B:CD status 4
Mar 28 11:56:01 raspberrypi bluetoothd[3884]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr FD:B8:73:ED:6B:CD type 0 status 0x4
Mar 28 11:56:01 raspberrypi bluetoothd[3884]: src/adapter.c:resume_discovery()
```

What can I do to debug this?
Anybody who had the same problems?